# Travelling Visual Studio developers

Tags: visual-studio

I am about to travel to Europe (I'm Australian but imagine this is a similar circumstance for US users and simply flipped for European users).

However, there is the slim possibility I will need to do some Visual Studio work while I'm travelling.

As I see it I have three options:

1. Leave a desktop PC on at home, access remotely via net cafes.
2. Carry a laptop with me on the trip, upload files as required using public wifi.
3. Option 2 but instead buy cheap light netbook that is miraculously capable of running VS.

Does anyone have any experience or advice to shed on any of these options?

For reference, [this existing post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661421/are-there-any-drawbacks-to-running-visual-studio-remotely) suggests that VS remotely for short distances is okay, but over longer distances could be more problematic.  I've used VS via RDP to a US server before and it was pretty laggy but for small changes I could get by.

Concerns I have that you may have some experience with:

- Weight of luggage (ideally like to travel light)
- Security of laptop (imagine it'll be too heavy to carry around all the time so have to leave it at hotel/hostel etc. and hope for the best)
- Security of data (don't want someone stealing RDP access to my home PC)
- Security of FTP (don't want someone stealing FTP passwords over wireless)

Comment: Just as a point of reference, http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/default.asp?joel.3.369910.12 discusses the RDP situation (including one user who used RDP in same situation, i.e. EU -> AU, who said it was bearable).

Comment: Didn't mention using VS though..

Comment: RDP is only as reliable as the closest internet connection that happens to have the correct ports open. I've had pretty bad luck with this in hotels in London. Take a laptop.

Comment: That's a great point. Most hostels throughout Europe have tons of other users and often have proxies preventing decent port access for lots of stuff or speed limiters anyway when things are open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used to leave a home PC on with VS and use services like GoToMyPc or LogMeIn or some similar service.

Since I have started using a laptop, I just carry the thing with me with VPN connectivity on business trips along with a 3G data card.

But seriously, if on vacation, I do *not* want to take my laptop with me.

**security**

First and foremost, encrypt the contents of the HDD - be safe.

If I am on a business trip, the laptop is with me so I am not as concerned with where it is. If I am on vacation, I do not know that I want to take one with me.

If is important then I would keep my laptop/pc at work ON and there will be someone that has access to turn it on/reboot it. So I would carry a light laptop that lets me connect and work if I need it. If that goes down, I can always head into a cybercafe.

**database**

If you are anticipating working, bring your dev database with you. I know it hogs space and memory (while in use), but it pulling data over the wire has taken long enough to make me lose concentration.

**standalone**

Make the laptop standalone so that it can work without a connection to VPN or internet - coverage is not the best / uniform in all areas.

Comment: Any experience using VS while on vacation?

Answer (score 4):

I'd go with option #2 (**carry a laptop that can run VS**).

This way you can use the "more convenient" method if it works well (use it as a RDP client if the connection is low-latency enough), but you can still work locally if the connection you find is not reliable.

I think the bottom line is, **always have a backup method when depending on networks that are far away and beyond your control**.

**Edit:** Regarding the additional security concerns, most of those are things you should deal with anyway, traveling or not. If the stuff you're working with is that sensitive, you should probably improve the security of your remote work environment with a VPN and more secure file transfer method. Before you take your laptop anywhere, know what your plan is if you were to lose it.

Comment: Makes sense.  Fortunately reliability isn't the biggest concern (if network is inaccessible then I just put off the work by a day).

Answer (score 3):

It's a vacation.  How do you expect to rest up properly if you're always worrying about work.  Leave the phone at home too.

Comment: Yeah agree.  It's just I plan on going for 2 months and have clients that depend on me if something goes to hell in my absence.  I think I'm inclined to the RDP route (as this is a backup plan that hopefully won't have to happen) but only if it is going to work if it needs to.

Comment: If clients depend on you, generally speaking everything *will* go to crap while you're on vacation.

Comment: Sounds like you need a bit more redundancy at the office so that someone else can handle things in your absence.

Comment: Yeah, I'm a sole freelancer and everyone else I know works with PHP and wordpress only (I'm using ASP.NET MVC and C# forms apps).

Answer (score 1):

I tried installing VS2010 on my NetBook and it was a no-go.  I was, however, able to install Expression Blend/Web which is good for most tasks.

Edit: To make this more useful... my netbook is HP Mini 1100 Series w/1GB RAM running Windows 7 "Starter"

Comment: Visual Studio 2008 is just-about-usable on my Samsung NC10 (with 2GB RAM), but I certainly wouldn't want to use it daily.

Comment: Pretty usable on my comparable Samsung netbook that I purchased based on your advice

Answer (score 1):

Use TrueCrypt for encrypting your harddisk. Use VPN, SSH or something similar for remote connections. I always bring my laptop, but in case I would lose it, it's just a brick for the finder, and I have a good backup system that makes me able to get up and running on another computer quickly.

Comment: I just read about TrueCrypt sounds very cool.  It's a deficiency in my knowledge but how would VPN/SSH help protect the RDP details when I login from say a net cafe PC?

Comment: Netcafes are inherently unsafe for accessing confidential data. You need trust for the device that encrypts/decrypts data for your connection. You can use VPN and SSH for encrypting RDP connections from a laptop that you brought yourself.

Comment: Thanks, I guessed as much.  Nothing you can do against a keylogger I guess.

Answer (score 1):

beware: i don't know where you are going in europe, but do not count on a reliable internet connection in a hotel. it generally works, but when it does not, don't count on the personnel to repair it. of course, if you also carry your own connection (G3 or EDGE on your mobile phone), then this will not be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using the option 2 when working on your source code.

I also recommand using **Git** so you can work with a source control while being disconnected from the office source control. When you get an access, you can sync your whole repository with your office repository.

Of course, it all depend on which source control provider you are using.

For the occasional stuff that are not on Git, use a VPN for enhanced security.

Answer (score 0):

My experience:

1) Purchased a small netbook (Samsung netbook with 2gb or so of RAM, I can lookup exact model number if anyoned interested but I think it's comparable to, or just above the NC10 (just comment if interested)).

2) Internet is *bad* in Europe (at least the options available to trav ellers). Something to note.

3) The netbook performance was absolutely fine. You don't want to be doing too much dev because of the small screen (though it was only really an issue for me because I got sick of the trackpad and didn't have a separate mouse) but it's honestly pretty fast and easy to use for .NET MVC development in Visual Studio.